# Testing that a particular image was copied to pasteboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, uipasteboard

I'm writing a test to verify a feature which copies an image to the pasteboard.

Here's the test, as I would prefer to write it:

```
// reset the paste board
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard.image = nil; //<-- this explodes
XCTAssertNil(UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard.image);

// Grab some random existing image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some-image"];
MJKMyClass *myInstance = [[myInstance alloc] initWithImage:image];
[myInstance doSomethingThatCopiesImageToPasteboard]

XCTAssertNotNil(UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard.image);
```

This fails with:

```
failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[UIPasteboard setImage:]: Argument is not an object of type UIImage [(null)]"
```

Which is surprising, because, according to the UIPasteboard header, image is a nullable field.

```
@interface UIPasteboard(UIPasteboardDataExtensions)
<...>    
@property(nullable,nonatomic,copy) UIImage *image __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
<...>
@end
```

I presume this means they are doing a runtime check on the argument, even though it is nullable.

Things I have tried:

- comparing objects by id doesn't work because UIImage's are copied by the generalPastboard.image (every time you call UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard.image you can a different instance)
- comparing by PNG representation might work, but seems gnarly.
- comparing by image size has been my closest bet so far, but also seems roundabout.

Comment: You might try `.items = []` for resetting.

Comment: Thank you! If you post as answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the pasteboard without having to pass `nil` by using the `items` property:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard.items = @[];
```

Or in Swift:

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().items = []
```

For comparing UIImages, you might want to look at some other questions:

- [How to compare two UIImage objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects)
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uiimage+compare